# Can a variable be passed to format() to pad?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting, padding

With new-style formatting, we can do:

```
In [262]: '{:_>10}'.format('test')
Out[262]: '______test'
```

Instead of the underscore (or whatever character), can this be replaced by a variable? So if:

```
double_dashes = '--'
```

Can we somehow incorporate this variable in call to `format()` so we get:

```
--------------------test
```

Comment: Your question is twofold: 1) Can I use a variable to hold the fill character? and 2) Can I use a two dashes as the fill character? The answers are yes, and no, respectively. Which part are you most interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instead of the underscore (or whatever character), can this be replaced by a variable?

Yes, that is fairly easy using a nested `{}`:

```
>>> '{:{}>10}'.format('test', 'x')
'xxxxxxtest'
```

> Can we somehow incorporate this variable in call to format() so we get:
>
> ```
> --------------------test
> ```

No. The fill character string must only be one character long.